# Use facebook sharer.php to share on a page wall

Tags: php, facebook

I want to link a user to make a share post on my fb company page without having to authenticate. Currently I can get them to share on their own wall with:

`<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=xxx&amp;p[summary]=xxx&amp;p[url]=xxx&amp;&p[images][0]=xxx"></a>`

But I'm not sure how I can get this to share to a page's wall rather than their timeline.

I got somewhat close by using the dialog feature:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=xxx&link=xxx&picture=xxx&name=xxx&caption=xxx&description=xxx&redirect_uri=xxx

But that just showed it as a normal share but done "via appName", unless there is a step I'm missing to link my app to my facebook page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the sharer.php method is used only to share only on the user's timeline.

If you want to ask the user to post on a page's timeline, you have to create an app, ask the user to authenticate it and then use the Facebook APIs to post on their behalf. I guess that will be cumbersome in your case, so I would just suggest you redirect to the particular Facebook page.

Comment: I have been given the requirement that a user can share a photo on this companies facebook page wall for a competition so that they can track entries (if they post it on their own wall it can't be tracked). If I go down the app authentication route, I can post to my page wall as them right? That way I could track fb entries to the competition?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In that case the app route is the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can't !

To publish on YOUR page timeline, users need to have the rights to do it (be admin, writer, ...) : it's a manual requirement on the Facebook interface.